# What is the simplest way to capitalize first letter of every sentence in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, capitalization

I have been working in LaTeX for a while, and during the typing I noticed that many places I skipped pressing the Shift key to make the first letter of a sentence capital. After checking here and there on internet, I found that LaTeX doesn't have any option to do that automatically and there are some macros etc which can do, but I want to know if there is any simple way to do it. Especially when you have a report of hundreds of pages and finding each one is a bit hard to manually update to a capital letter.

MS Word does it automatically.

Comment: It would be _much_ better to just use your editor to fix your input file than to try to do this with macros which would be very fragile, likely to get it wrong in many cases and be incompatible with many packages. Just use your editor to query-replace a regular expression such as `\.\s+[a-z]` and say whether to replace it by the uppercase or not.

Comment: thanks, but my report is too big to be checked like this, as still i miss lot of cases then. As it can be easily catched by other softwares. any way thanks for suggestion.

Comment: If it can be easily caught by other software it can be easily caught by your _editor_ you should not leave this to the typesetter. (Note that MSWord combines the functions of an editor with a typesetter so the fact that Word can do it is not that relevant to whether TeX ought to do it)

Comment: Why should a regular expression for end-of-sentence punctuation followed by white space followed by a lower case letter miss any cases ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It would miss all cases where the begin of the sentence is *not* preceded by a period. E.g. `\section{blub} this is a begin`. You can't avoid to have to proof read a text - even with with Word.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sure but you can make the regex smarter to catch sections. (harder is to catch one-off macros) but I agree you need to read to check which is why it's much better to fix the source than have this change on the fly at run time

Comment: Actually its a scientific report where i can get the fullstop between formulae and expressions, it has programming code so there has to be something which should take care of these all thing. Definately proof reading i will do, but at least if the capitalization is not an issue i will not be worried about the first letter of sentences.